# sum value column b only if value in column a is unique

Tags: excel, sum, duplicates, countif, vba

looking for direction on how to do the following, thank you in advance for any insight provided:

I want to sum the total values in column C (Total Lines per order) ONLY once per the value in column A (Sales Order). So Sales Order "A" appears three times in column A, however I only want to sum the corresponding value in column C one time as part of the sum, and not include the duplicate lines.

I could use the "Delete Duplicates" function, but I want to keep the unique item Part Numbers on each line on the report.

Example:

```
Sales Order "A" has 3 total Lines
Sales Order "B" has 4 total lines
Sales order "C" has 2 total lines
Sales Order "D" has 5 total lines          
                  = 14 total lines
```

I've attached an example list in the link Below

[image]

Comment: You can use VBA with `Dictionary` object to achieve this

Comment: You forgot E, total lines is 16 with E.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you want is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C2:C14/COUNTIF(A2:A14,A2:A14))
```

[image]

Comment: Keeping it simple, I like it. You don't even ignore duplicates, you just divide them out. This deserves two +1s.